# Get data from free host and deleteing html tags with that data (Android)

Tags: php, android

I have an application that get a very simple data from my free host (I uploaded a php file in my host), and show that in a textview in my application.
The data that my app get from host is a very simple (a text that my php file send to my app is like the result of this code : print "user exist";
but with that "user exist" my application shows a HTML tag with it, I think it is because of my Host, but how can I delete that HTML tag and just get the result of my php file to my android application.
the image : http://8pic.ir/images/5i9y87e8xp9wocu1qaui.png
I don't know from where (android cod or php in my host) the problem can resove than I copy both of them here :

my HTML code :

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("mysql14.000webhost.com", "mohad", "229");
    mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $result = mysql_query("select Password from tbl_users where Username = '$user' ");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($row[0]){print "user exist";}else print "no user";


    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

my android code (Main activity) :

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public static String netdata;
private Button btnGet;
private TextView txtShowdata;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    txtShowdata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShowdata);

    btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
    btnGet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Getdata().execute("http://mohad.webuda.com/test.php", "mohad");
            txtShowdata.setText(netdata);
        }
    }); 

}// end onCreat()

}// end Class
```

and here is myAsync class :

```
public class Getdata extends AsyncTask <Object, Object, Object>{

StringBuilder strBuilder;
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

    try{

        URL url_mylink = new URL(params[0].toString());
        URLConnection url_connect = url_mylink.openConnection();



        // Send to host
        String sendingdata = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(params[1].toString(), "UTF8");
        url_connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(url_connect.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(sendingdata);
        osw.flush();


        // Get from host
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url_connect.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String temp_line = null;
        strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while((temp_line=bufR.readLine()) != null){
            strBuilder.append(temp_line);
        }


    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}

    return strBuilder;
}// end doInBackground()

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Main.netdata = result.toString();

}// end onPostExecute()

}// end Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, I explain the resolve here for others may have the same problem as mine. I add a pipe mark '|' at end of my comment in php code and use subString in android code like code below :

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public static String netdata;
private Button btnGet;
private TextView txtShowdata;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    txtShowdata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShowdata);

    btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
    btnGet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            netdata = "";
            new Getdata().execute("http://mohad.webuda.com/test.php", "mohad");

            final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please wait..");
            pd.show();

            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(netdata != ""){
                                pd.cancel();
                                tafkik(netdata);
                                txtShowdata.setText(netdata);
                                timer.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 1, 1000);
        }// end onclick()
    }); 

}// end onCreat()

private void tafkik(String temp){

    for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++){
        if(temp.charAt(i)=='|'){
            netdata = temp.substring(0, i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

}// end Class
```